# How run a function only after all deferred are resolved by using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, .when

I don't understand where is the problem, I've read several questions here, but nothing something like that.
I can't use a function to return a promise, I need just tu put all the promises in one array and pass it to the "$.when" function.

```
var pr = [];
var count = 3; 
while(count--){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     var def = $.Deferred();
     pr.push(def.promise());    
     console.log('COUNT: '+count); def.resolve(count); 
   }, Math.random()*2000);
}  

$.when.apply($, pr).done(function(d){
     console.log("LOG:",d);
});
```

Obviously doesn't work because in WHEN pr is empty by that time.
How can sort it out?

Comment: You need to create the deferreds immediately (so that you can pass them into  `$.when`), not somewhen in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only adding the deferreds to the array after they've run. The point is you want them in the array up front and then when they all *resolve* execute some functionality.

```js
var defA = $.Deferred();
var pr = [defA.promise()];
var count = 3; 

var defB = $.Deferred();
pr.push(defB.promise());     
    
var defC = $.Deferred();
pr.push(defC.promise());     
    

setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log('COUNT: '+count--); defB.resolve(count); 

}, Math.random()*2000);

setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log('COUNT: '+count--); defC.resolve(count); 
    defA.resolve(11011);
}, Math.random()*2000);


$.when.apply($, pr).done(function(d){
     console.log("LOG:",d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For your update, you'll need to also use a closure, as `count` will have changed by the time the async work has completed (ie, without it you'll get logged `count: 0` three times). This closure also has the neat side effect of keeping `def` in local scope for each iteration. More info in this Q/A: 
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

```js
var pr = [];
var count = 3; 
while(count--){
   
   (function(x){
       var def = $.Deferred();
       pr.push(def.promise());    
       setTimeout(function(){        
        
          console.log('COUNT: '+ x); 
          def.resolve(x); 
       }, Math.random()*2000);
     
   })(count);
}  

$.when.apply($, pr).done(function(){
     console.log("LOG:",arguments);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT - changed the callback to `when` so that you can see that, even though they resolve in a random order, you get the results back in the order they went in. (ie `aruments[0]` will always be `2` even though that one possibly didnt resolve first)

Comment: How can I do that if I create $.Deferred in a while/for/each?

Comment: @Donovant asking the right question is a good start. Dont ask `a` if you're question is really `b`. But, whether they are in a line or a loop, shouldnt make a difference. Create the deferrd outside of the async work it's doing.

Comment: @Donovant I assume you didnt intend to `count--` twice?

Comment: @Donovant answer updated. It is a little more complex with a loop, but only just.